# Is there a reason why Angular CLI configures to not load scripts on demand?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am new to Angular 2 and module loaders. I am building my project using Angular CLI. I learnt that Webpack loads modules that are necessary for an application (tree-shaking?) and packages them into one or few files. I am still confused between this and downloading script files based on user demand. My Angular application will probably have about 100 components when complete. Will it be wise to go the default CLI way and deliver all components to the client at once or is it better to load them on demand?

Comment: What do you mean by *"load"*? Angular 2 and the CLI supports lazy *loading* of modules, but you *download* the files once at the start. This avoids network overhead when the user e.g. switches to a different tab. Tree shaking is about removing the code you *don't* need.

Comment: By loading I meant delivering the JS to client. So I understand that Webpack loads the JS into memory only when required, but the download has already completed. Am I right? Do you think this is wise if there are 100 components in the application? Will it help if I split my components into multiple modules?

Comment: One point of SPAs is that users can move quickly around the app without waiting for pages to load, because they already have the pages. The trade off is the initial download size. If that trade off doesn't work for you, maybe an SPA isn't the way to go? But I would encourage you to find out *if there actually is a performance problem* before spending time on solving it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the long answer, but it seems from the question that we need to go through some basics first.

### Module Bundlers

A clever module bundler would be able to:

- Statically analyze your imports (and the imports of your imports, etc), to do tree-shaking, which is excluding code that is never imported.

  This only works when the script is meant to be used as a module. That's why a good module bundler would give you a way to exclude some legacy scripts from this operation.

  Note that this is not uglification or minimization. A minifier / uglifier might remove code that looks not used based on its understanding of the code, but that, if gone too far, can remove some actually used code (for example, trying to load a function by name where the name is dynamic in a string. Minifier might think the function is never used).

  Tree shaking only works on imports, because they are static, cannot be dynamic. SystemJS is a module bundler that can make them dynamic, but this means loading a lot extra files in separate requests, causing longer response time to the user.
- Properly optimize the total number of files, and their serve them in the best way

  That is, a single file saves HTTP requests, and loads fast, except in situations where the file is very large and the browser is not blocked by the file and can load multiple files. Except even loading multiple files has its limits as the browser won't parallelize so many files.

  A good bundler would give you some extras on top of that like statistics about file sizes, and like generating unique hashes in the filename based on file content so that the URL to a changed file can always be different when the file content changes. It would inject the dynamic name into your HTML as well.
- It would give you a way to lazy-load module **-- this is what you are talking about**

  You know your application better than anyone. You have certain expectations about your users. You know what parts of the application better be ready when the application loads and take no time to load, and which will just make the initial load too big and actually be negatively affecting the user experience.

  A good bundler would allow you to specify which bits to "lazy load", or separate into a different file, and transparently load that file for you when these bits are requested by the user.

### Webpack and Angular CLI

As you may have guessed, Webpack 2 does everything we said a good bundler should do. It:

- Loads files in proper bundle scripts
- Applies optimizations like tree-shaking, hashing, and minimization
- Allows excluding files from tree-shaking or entire processing
- Injects dynamic script names into your HTML
- Handles lazy-loading transparently, on build time generating multiple bundles, and on run time loading the bundles transparently for you

The thing is: all these (and way more features) are optional. Many of them require plugins (built-in and 3rd party), and configuration (for example, how far to go with minification, what HTML file to inject scripts into, what files to load in the bundle, what filename format to use, etc. etc.).

The more Webpack features you use, the more your Webpack config goes out of hand.

And that's where the Angular CLI kicks in.

It has perfect defaults, and includes so many features. It encapsulates the whole configuration for adding these features.

One of these features that is specific to your question is **lazy loading**.

#### Lazy Loading

The way you tell Webpack to lazy load something is by calling an API that's not yet approved as a standard. It also allows other ways that are more similar to node modules than standard EcmaScript modules.

The Angular Router allows you to skip this syntax, and use Angular Router specific syntax to lazy load Angular Modules (think `@NgModule({})` not EcmaScript/Node module).

For example, to lazy-load the `/admin` module, assuming it looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ...],
  declarations: [ ... ],
  providers: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: '', component: AdminComponent }
    ]),
    ...
  ],
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

You change the routes of the `AppModule` from:

```
const Routes = [
  ...,
  { path: '/admin', loadChildren: () => AdminModule }
];
```

To:

```
const Routes = [
  ...,
  { path: '/admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }
];
```

And then you'll leave the Angular Router, Angular CLI, and Webpack to do the magic.

Just don't keep your `import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';` line lying round, because this WiLL load the module in the main application bundle even if `AdminModule` is not used. Because as said tree shaking is a static process that works only on EcmaScript imports analysis.

#### Extras.

The Angular CLI adds the `--routing` parameter to the `ng generate module` and `ng new` commands, which add new files like `admin-routing.module.ts` and `app-routing.module.ts` files to separate the routes into their own file. This is nice and it's also only organizational.

A common mistake is to think that you need to reference the `AdminRoutesModule` file in the `AppRoutesModule`, which is wrong. The different modules and extra files don't make any difference.

#### Example

If you want to look at more code, I have a simple repository here to look at:

https://github.com/meligy/routing-angular-cli

**Note:**

Unfortunately lazy loading is broken in Angular CLI beta 24. It's tracked [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3204). I'll see if I can work on a pull request based on the solution suggested in the issue.